# Attitude.RotationMatrix vs. Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Shouldn't the RotationMatrix returned by the motion sensor be equal to the Matrix created using Yaw, Pitch and Roll values from the same motion reading?

Having following code:

```
MotionReading mr = motion.CurrentValue;
Matrix m1 = mr.Attitude.RotationMatrix;
var yaw = mr.Attitude.Yaw;
var pitch = mr.Attitude.Pitch;
var roll = mr.Attitude.Roll;
Matrix m2 = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yaw, pitch, roll);
```

Shouldn't m1 and m2 be equal? What am I missing there?

Answer (score 0):

How is your `RotationMatrix` calculated?
If you are rotating a model on more than one axis, sometimes can occur a problem that the first rotation actually rotates the other 2 axis, and maybe that's why `CreateFromYawPitchRoll` gives you a `Matrix` that is different from your `RotationMatrix`.
I suggest you to use `CreateFormYawPitchRoll`, or you can try using `Quaternions`.